# FormField.Add method does not return a reference to the new field (bug?)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using Word 2010 to create an electronic form but there appears to be a bug in the `Add` method of the `FormField` collection; I want to know if there is a way around it.

In the form I have a table, asking for information about staff members, which allows additional rows to be added by pressing a button. The code adds a new row to the table then goes through each cell in the new row creating form fields.

```
Private Sub AddStaffRow(t As Table)

    Dim rowNum As Integer
    Dim ff As FormField

    ' Add a new row
    t.Rows.Add
    rowNum = t.Rows.Count

    ' Insert form fields in to the cells
    ' Staff role dropdown
    Set ff = ActiveDocument.FormFields.Add(t.Cell(rowNum, 1).Range, wdFieldFormDropDown)
    ff.Name = "staff_role" & rowNum
    With ff.DropDown.ListEntries
        .Add "Principle Investigator"
        .Add "Sub Investigator"
        .Add "Research Nurse"
        .Add "Practice Nurse"
        .Add "Administrator"            
    End With

    ' Staff name textbox
    Set ff = ActiveDocument.FormFields.Add(t.Cell(rowNum, 2).Range, wdFieldFormTextInput)
    ff.Name = "staff_name" & rowNum

    ' GCP certificate available
    Set ff = ActiveDocument.FormFields.Add(t.Cell(rowNum, 3).Range, wdFieldFormDropDown)
    ff.Name = "staff_gcp" & rowNum
    With ff.DropDown.ListEntries
        .Add "Yes"
        .Add "No"
        .Add "NA"
    End With
End Sub
```

The fist field added works correctly, the dropdown is created and named with options added. However, when the next field is added the `FormField` collection count increments, the field appears in the document, but the reference returned from the function is for the *first* field (the staff role dropdown)

The [documentation states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838734%28v=office.14%29.aspx) the return value is (supposed to be) a reference to the `FormField` object added to the collection:

[image: MS-Word VBA documentation snippet]

The returned reference is incorrect because after the code has completed this first dropdown field has the `name` of the last field added and looks like this

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or is there a way around this "bug"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to ensure that the range does not include the end-of-cell range marker before inserting the FormField.

e.g.

```
Dim r As Word.Range
Set r = t.Cell(rowNum,1).Range
r.SetRange r.Start, r.End-1
Set ff = ActiveDocument.FormFields.Add(r, wdFieldFormDropDown)
```

Comment: Your solution works, thanks. But can you explain why you must not select the end-of-cell marker? I still think this is a bug but I'd like to be proved wrong if it's documented somewhere.

Comment: > 'can you explain' No, but end-of-cell markers can't be replaced in the same way that, say, end-of-paragraph markers can. So when you try to modify the content of a range that contains an end-of-cell marker, you may encounter a problem. Bug? I would describe the Word Range object as a very poor piece of design that's unnecessarily hard to work with. Perhaps adapted from Excel's Range rather than re-conceived for Word. FWIW, I rarely describe things as "bugs" on the principle that it makes them sound like accidents, not fixable and sometimes even avoidable consequences of human error :-)

Comment: As an afterthought, I suppose "bug" at least in the sense that the object model would ideally raise an exception in that scenario.

Comment: I agree it should raise an exception but I still think it's a bug. The collection should return a reference to the new field added not a reference to the first field in the collection; irrespective of the range used. If the range is invalid then a new field should not be added and, as you suggest, an exception thrown.